# Sorting in MySQL/

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a problem trying to work out some logic when trying to sort. Even went back to Excel to work out simple logic.

```
What I have is :-
ColA    ColB
100022  33
100022  36
100024  28
100024  32
100024  41
100024  52
100026  38
100038  28
100038  42
100038  48
100038  59
```

What I want to do is sort by Column B (heightest to lowest) BUT I dont want Column A to have the same values next to each other.Sorting the above will have 33 & 36 (with 100022) next to each other (and 42&48) with 100038 next to each other. As long as Column B is sorted as best it can from heightest to lowest and Column A's values are never next to each other (Unless absolutely necessary) I'm happy.

Ideally I am after a logic to end up with something like this ..

```
100024  28
100038  28
100022  33
100024  32
100022  36
100026  38
100038  42
100024  41
100038  48
100024  52
100038  59
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Brad

Comment: B appears to be sorted roughly 'lowest to highest'

Comment: What is the relation between Col A and Col B? If they are not related to each other why we have to store them in same table and try to sort?

Comment: Which school's assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce that no two values from `ColA` appear adjacent, then one option would be to assign a row number to each value in a given `ColA` block, and then order to ensure that adjacent values do not occur.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @ColA = NULL;

SELECT t.ColA, t.ColB
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE WHEN @ColA = ColA THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
        @ColA:=ColA AS ColA,
        ColB
    FROM
        yourTable
    ORDER BY ColA, ColB DESC
) t
ORDER BY t.rn, t.ColB DESC
```

You mentioned in your question that wanted `ColB` sorted from highest to lowest, which I have done.  If you want ascending ordering, just remove the `DESC` from the above query.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester